# XSLT - add a namespace declaration to some children

Tags: xml, xslt

For some reasons, I need to alter an existing xml file and I would like to use xslt to do that. I need to move some namespace declaration from root node to child.

Basically I am starting with a file looking like this :

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="http://ns1" xmlns:ns2="http://ns2" xmlns:ns3="http://ns3">
<env:Header>
    <ns1:parent11>

        <ns1:child11>value</ns1:child11>
        <ns1:child11>value</ns1:child11>
        <ns1:child11>value</ns1:child11>

        <ns1:child12>
            <ns2:child21>value</ns2:child21>
            <ns2:child22>value</ns2:child22>
        </ns1:child12>

    </ns1:parent11>
</env:Header>


<env:Body>
    <ns3:parent31>
        <ns3:child31>value</ns3:child31>
        <ns3:child32>value</ns3:child32>

        <ns3:child33>
            <ns2:parent2>
                <ns2:child23>value</ns2:child23>
                <ns2:child23>value</ns2:child23>
                <ns2:child23>value</ns2:child23>
            </ns2:parent2>
        </ns3:child33>

    </ns3:parent31>
</env:Body>
```

And I need to end with something like this :

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns1="http://ns1" xmlns:ns2="http://ns2" xmlns:ns3="http://ns3">
<env:Header>
    <parent11 xmlns="http://ns1">

        <child11>value</child11>
        <child11>value</child11>
        <child11>value</child11>

        <child12>
            <ns2:child21>value</ns2:child21>
            <ns2:child22>value</ns2:child22>
        </child12>

    </parent11>
</env:Header>


<env:Body>

    <parent31 xmlns="http://ns3">
        <child31>value</child31>
        <child32>value</child32>

        <child33>
            <parent2 xmlns="http://ns2">
                <child23>value</child23>
                <child23>value</child23>
                <child23>value</child23>
            </parent2>
        </child33>

    </parent31>
</env:Body>
```

I am a complete newbie in xslt (I choose it because I think this is the right way to do it), so I am stuck at the very begining and I don't even know how to start.

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercise? AFAICT, the input and output are semantically identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution XSLT 1.0 / XSLT 2.0:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:ns1="http://ns1"
    xmlns:ns2="http://ns2"
    xmlns:ns3="http://ns3"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="ns1:* | ns2:* | ns3:*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ns1"
    xmlns:ns2="http://ns2" xmlns:ns3="http://ns3">
    <env:Header>
        <parent11 xmlns="http://ns1">

            <child11>value</child11>
            <child11>value</child11>
            <child11>value</child11>

            <child12>
                <child21 xmlns="http://ns2">value</child21>
                <child22 xmlns="http://ns2">value</child22>
            </child12>

        </parent11>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <parent31 xmlns="http://ns3">
            <child31>value</child31>
            <child32>value</child32>

            <child33>
                <parent2 xmlns="http://ns2">
                    <child23>value</child23>
                    <child23>value</child23>
                    <child23>value</child23>
                </parent2>
            </child33>

        </parent31>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**Description:**

Upper template removes the namespace-prefix - e.g. `ns1` - for matched elements.

Second template is an *identity-copy* for all other elements, attributes and text.

XSLT-Processors removes the namespace of childs within the same namespace on its own.